# xfce - Start a window on the workspace where the process is run

Tags: xfce, workspaces, window, xfwm4

Most of the time I open a window from a virtual terminal on a workspace, say W1, via a shell. For instance

```
zsh% libreoffice document.odt &
```

Sometimes it can take a few seconds before the window of the corresponding process appears. Therefore I often switch to another workspace, say W2, where I am working on something else. After some latency period, the window of the process (libreoffice in the above example) appears on W2.

Is it possible to modify the settings (of xfwm4?) so that the new window appears always on the workspace where its process is run, namely W1?